# LinkContainer with a full URL - React-Bootstrap-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I'm wondering how I can have my LinkContainer/NavItem link to an external URL. I tried:

```
<LinkContainer to="https://www.example.com">
 <NavItem eventKey={1}>LinkedIn</NavItem>
</LinkContainer>
```

In which case I get the error:

`A path must be pathname + search + hash only, not a full URL`

I've also tried:

`<NavItem eventKey={1} href="https://www.example.com"></NavItem>`

The above yields no error, but doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `Link` from `react-router` commented by @yussan, you can add a target value and it should work. I'm using it to link external social networks, like this:

`import { Link } from 'react-router'`

`<Link to="https://facebook.com/mypage" target="new">Facebook</Link>`

I know its an old thread, but I faced this issue today and wanted to share the solution.

You'll probably be able to do something like this:

`<Link to="https://www.example.com" target="new">
     <NavItem eventKey={1}>LinkedIn</NavItem>
</Link>`

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 1):

that component is based on `react-router` `Link` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router , and only used to transition within website.

for example : `/people` `/people/id`

if you want create direct link to other website, you have to create own link component with `a href`.